# Ipe can't find pdflatex

Tags: texlive, paths, linux, ipe

Okay I installed texlive 2012, just by following the guides from http://www.tug.org/texlive/.

Now when I downloadend, compiled and installed [ipe7](http://ipe7.sourceforge.net/), the latest version. Now when I try something, draw/text etc, ipe tells me that it can't find pdflatex. Now I guessed that since I installed it from tug.org and not by a ubuntu package that it is now installed underneath a different directory. Pdflatex is located in the folder `/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux/`

Now I found in the manual that you can use the command flag `IPELATEXDIR` to point to a different location where pdflatex is located. So I started `ipe --IPELATEXDIR=/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux/` but it still tells me that it can't find pdflatex?

I tried to find a log file in `~/.ipe/` but only the latex file is located there.

Does anybody got any clue?

Comment: Does `pdflatex` compiling normally? Did you insert the `texlive` folder in you `$PATH` variable? What is the result of `echo $PATH` on the terminal?

Comment: Oh no that I didn't do. I have my own custom command for compiling latex files which makes calls then pdflatex by just ``/dir/../dir/pdflatex``. I will try to add the folder to $PATH variable. Thanks for the hint, hopefully this will solve the problem.

Comment: Here is my `$PATH` variable: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux/
`

Comment: Hmmm no it still says it can't find pdflatex. My $PATH variable is now ``PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux/:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games``

Comment: How did you change you variable?

Comment: I just added ``/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux/`` to the path folder? Saved the .bashrc and restarted the terminal? If thats what you mean

Comment: Probably your path is updated only when you open the terminal. When you logoff and login again it'll be changed back to the default. This happened to me once. I suggest you to insert at the end of you `~/.profile` file `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/i386-linux:$PATH; export PATH 
MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH 
INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH; export INFOPATH
`

Comment: It does not work unfortunately. I added the PATH and restarted the computer. Further it still does not seem to find pdflatex since it says ``The program 'pdflatex' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-base``. While the correct path where pdflatex is located is for sure included in the PATH folder.

Comment: So you have to fake the installation of `texlive-latex-base` and then any program which request it will be work (I guess). Read the section *Fake Packages* from here http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/14757

Comment: Just followed all the steps, but didn't work either :(

Maybe it is because I'm running 64 bit?

Comment: Try to compile Ipe for your processor.

Comment: Btw: The curent version of TeXLive is 2013.

Comment: From the manual I get that `IPELATEXDIR` is an environment variable, not a command line option. So setting `export IPELATEXDIR=/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux` in your `.bashrc` might be the solution (with 2013, when you install the new TeX Live).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`IPELATEXPATH` is an environment variable, *not* a command line option.

So either you call the program as

```
IPELATEXPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux ipe
```

or, better, you set

```
export IPELATEXPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux
```

in your `.bashrc` file (or `.profile` or whatever you prefer).

*Caveat.* Older versions of Ipe might want `IPELATEXDIR`.

Comment: I know this question is very old, but it remains close to the top of search results, so this comment may be helpful. The environment variable is `IPELATEXPATH` (not ...`DIR`). Until recently there was a bug in ipe that prevented it from invoking luatex (though not pdftex) correctly in this situation, but at least in 7.2.21 it is now fixed, and it even respects $PATH.

Comment: @AlexWatson I trust you.