# IPE: An error occurred during the Pdflatex run

Tags: errors, ipe

I have the same problem as here:
[Ipe latex, error with pdflatex command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187053/ipe-latex-error-with-pdflatex-command)

but I don't understand the answer :(

Problem:
When I run IPE, I get this error:

> "An error occurred during the Pdflatex run There was an error trying
>   to run Pdflatex"

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.     A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: You have a created a label with a syntax error.  Please post the label you've made and we can help you find the error.

Comment: Thanks. Okay so I'm using IPE on a Mac. Normally I would draw a few diagrams then I'd hit the button where I can add text/maths text and add it to the diagrams. But for some reason, each time I try to do that now, I get the error above.

Comment: @MartinSchröder I'm not sure how I'm using an MWE..